# jQuery append() empty elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to retrieve json data and append to an `<option>` tag in HTML. But each time it also appends an empty  right after the specific elements. It looks like this.

```
<select>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option></option>
<option value="condition1">condition</option>
<option></option>
<option value="condition2">condition2</option>
<option></option>
</select>
```

Obviously it's suppose to append like below:

```
<select>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option value="condition1">condition</option>
<option value="condition2">condition2</option>
</select>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
for(var i=0; i<=option_array.length; i++){
          if(option_array.indexOf(condition)==-1){
          option_array.push(condition);

      $select.append('<option value="' + condition + '">' + condition + '<option>');
                  console.log("CONDITION!" + condition);
                  option_array.push(condition);

                 }
```

Here is the original HTML:

```
<select></select>
```

Any ideas of why this happen?

Comment: you are looping till `i<=option_array.length`. You should loop till length - 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason you are getting extra elements is you have another opening tag

```
+ '<option>');
   ^^^
```

You missed the /

```
+ '</option>');
   ^^^
```

Comment: This is Prefect reason.